# Can someone please guide me how to download the release of phpSPO?

Tags: sharepoint-online, api, php

I want to retrieve data from sharepoint via API but I can't install phpSPO. Composer method is relatively easy but is very complex for me. So, please share the link so I can download the release and also guide how I can use it later. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, please refer to this document to install phpSPO: https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO

Hope it can help you. Thanks for your understanding.